# Identify commit in which a particular file was deleted

Tags: git, file, commit, identity, delete-file

I am working on a project which is hosted on GIT. In some directory in my repo, somebody has deleted a file say [a.txt] at path [/home/git/myProject/generic]. Now, a lot of commits have happened on files in this directoty. I want to track down the commit in which this file was removed.

What I have tried.

```
git log --oneline myProject/generic
```

But this returns a lot of commits and its difficult to track down the exact commit.

I also tried

```
git log --oneline myProject/generic/a.txt
```

But this returns, path does not exist error.

Suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add `--`:

```
git log --oneline -- myProject/generic/a.txt
```

Comment: -- Just helps log command to identify whether user has passed a commit or path. -- refers to path. Right? Its not showing any commit when I specified -- switch.

Comment: Have you tried it? I did, and it works. Add `-1` if you want to see just most recent commit touching this file (supposedly one that deleted it).

Comment: I think you are right. Even though I am not able to see any commit after using this switch too. Something else has happened. But this is the right answer for the question I have asked. Thanks :)